# .height() adding decimal points to value

Tags: jquery

I have this function, which works as it needs to (I think it's pretty self explanatory). However, the outputted value is 473.4615384340286. I don't want all the .decimal points. I'd like to actually round up. The `.height()` of `#campaign-header`is 475px.

What's up with the decimals?

```
// add billboard height value to modal input
var inputBillboard = $('#campaign-header').height();
$('.billboard-height').val(inputBillboard);
```

Comment: Floating point math. The browser just rounds them off to the nearest pixel, though. It's not something you need to fix, unless its being displayed to the user. In that case, use Math.round or .toFixed() to make them look nice.

Comment: `Math.round` won't work. He wants to **round up**.

Comment: How does 473.4615384340286 ever round up to 475?

Comment: @chead23 No, but it's because I have a `border-bottom` pixel, which height doesn't account for. Which is okay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your div is 475px tall, then `.height()` will return 475 **only if** the div has no border or padding.  If it has a border or padding, it will return the height minus those dimensions.  If you want the total height, use `.outerHeight()`:

```
$('#campaign-header').outerHeight(false);
```

The parameter (false in this case), tells whether or not to include the margin in the calculation.

Answer (score 4):

To round it up you can use `Math.ceil()`:

```
var inputBillboard = Math.ceil($('#campaign-header').height());
```

Answer (score 2):

`Math.ceil()` is what you need:

```
var inputBillboard = Math.ceil($('#campaign-header').height());
$('.billboard-height').val(inputBillboard);
```

Comment: parseFloat isn't necessary

Comment: I was going to comment this.

Comment: Awesome...just what I need.

Comment: Was about to accept, however outerHeight() is what I was looking for in the end. Thanks fo the help though. Learned something new today.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use `.outerHeight()` instead of `.height()`.
`outerHeight` will return the height with the padding etc. of the element taken into account:

```
// add billboard height value to modal input
var inputBillboard = $('#campaign-header').outerHeight();
$('.billboard-height').val(inputBillboard);
```

More often than not, this is what people expect `.height()` to return. The difference in what you get and what you expect to get makes me wonder if this also applies to you.

You can also supply true to `outerHeight()` to make it so that it will take the elements margins into account too.

The function always returns an integer.

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/

If you don't want the size including padding, use Math.ceil on .height as suggested by BenM.

**edit:** JeffB beat me to it. :)

Comment: Ohhhh okay, outerheight() is definitely what I wanted!! Perfect!